# How to write to a text file only those fields which have data

Tags: .net, vba, textbox, streamwriter

Suppose if I have **10 Textboxes** but If i have only data to be entered in **"5"** of those Textboxes and I want to write only those **"5" textboxes data** to a text file.

and

Suppose if I have **10 Textboxes** but If i have only data to be entered in **"7"** of those Textboxes and I want to write only those **"7" textboxes data** to a text file.

What I'm saying is Everytime i try to enter the data, there's no sufficient data to enter in all those 10 TextBoxes I have, Sometimes i only have the data for 5 textboxes, and sometimes it's 7 textboxes.

So... How to achieve this.

> Note: I'm using some predefined text for all the textboxes... like < em > tag at the beginning of the text box and textbox data and then closing < /em > tag.

```
objWriter1.WriteLine("<em>" + BD1.Text + "</em>")
```

I don't want to display just the < em > tags when there's no data but I want to completely skip it.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you want to store it and reloaded to the right textboxes or way can't you not just simply check if the text is equal to "" and than skip it?

Comment: well i don't know how to check the text is equal to ""  and then skip it.... I'm new to the .Net so ... can u guide me here ???

Answer (score 0):

It seems a straight thing unless you have other requirement , 
only check for nullability &empty strings and write only those fields that have value , if you have more clarification please add it .

Answer (score 0):

In your class, declare a list for all the textboxes:

```
private List<TextBox> _textBoxes;
```

In your constructor somewhere:

```
public MyClass(){
  _textBoxes.Add(textBox1);
  _textBoxes.Add(textBox2);
  // etc
}
```

Now in your code, you can do this:

```
foreach(var textBox in _textBoxes){
   var text = textBox.Text.Replace("<em>", "").Replace("</em>", "");
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpt(text){
      // Do your saving here
   }
}
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: I'm using some predefined text for all the textboxes... like < em > tag at the beginning of the text box and textbox data and then closing < /em > tag.
I don't want to display just the < em > tags when there's no data but I want to completely skip it.

Comment: so you can textBox1.Text.Remove("<em>").Remove("</em>")

Comment: Isn't there any simple way to do it brother ... like check for the textbox and if it is null then simply skip it.... because i have lots of textboxes in my code and writing each one will become a huge code.

Comment: Well, if you have the <em></em> there, then it will never be null if I understood your question, and you'll have to remove those if you dont want to keep them. What you can do is to add all the textboxes to a list in your constructor, so you can reference each in a foreach loop later where you need this.

Comment: Actually this is my code... objWriter1.WriteLine("<em>" + BD1.Text + "</em>")

Comment: Editing my answer, hang in there :)

Comment: I'm sorry brother but i'm a complete novice and i don't know how to use your code. I'm trying to keep ur code "..... private List<TextBox> _textBoxes; ..... under this line of my code ".....Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click ....."

Comment: Maybe someone can help explain this - I'm down at the very basics of programming, wiht concepts such as constructors, private members etc. These are the very building blocks of object oriented programming. Not sure how to clarify for you further without writing a book :)

Comment: from ur code .... private List<TextBox> _textBoxes; .............. should i write like this............private List<TextBox> _textBoxes;
    BP1.Text
    BP2.Text